# Why is my supposedly parallel go program not parallel

Tags: concurrency, go, parallel-processing

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func alphabets() {
    for char := 'a'; char < 'a'+26; char++ {
        fmt.Printf("%c ", char)
    }
    wg.Done() //decrement number of goroutines to wait for
}

func numbers() {
    for number := 1; number < 27; number++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", number)
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)
    wg.Add(2) //wait for two goroutines

    fmt.Println("Starting Go Routines")
    go alphabets()
    go numbers()

    fmt.Println("\nWaiting To Finish")

    wg.Wait() //wait for the two goroutines to finish executing

    fmt.Println("\nTerminating Program")
}
```

I expect the output to be mixed up(for lack of a better word), but instead; a sample output is:

$ go run parallel_prog.go

Starting Go Routines
Waiting To Finish
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
Terminating Program

What I'm I missing?

Thanks,

Comment: Probably the first one finishes before the other one gets a chance to start. make them run longer and you'll see it in parallel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing nothing. It's working. The calls aren't showing up "interlaced" (mixed up) not because they're not being parallelized, but because they're happening *really fast*.

You can easily add some calls to `time.Sleep` to see the parallelization better. By sleeping, we know 100% that printing `alphabets` and `numbers` should be interlaced.

### Your program with `Sleep` calls to "force" interlacing

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func alphabets() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for char := 'a'; char < 'a'+26; char++ {
        fmt.Printf("%c ", char)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    }
}

func numbers() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for number := 1; number < 27; number++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", number)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
    }    
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting Go Routines")
    wg.Add(2)
    go alphabets()
    go numbers()

    fmt.Println("\nWaiting To Finish")
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("\nTerminating Program")
}
```

### Note

You probably already know this, but setting `GOMAXPROCS` doesn't have any effect on whether or not this example is executed in parallel, just how many resources it consumes.

> The GOMAXPROCS setting controls how many operating systems threads attempt to execute code simultaneously. For example, if GOMAXPROCS is 4, then the program will only execute code on 4 operating system threads at once, even if there are 1000 goroutines. The limit does not count threads blocked in system calls such as I/O.

Source: [Go 1.5 GOMAXPROCS Default](http://golang.org/s/go15gomaxprocs)

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the Go playground by any chance? When I run your code locally, I get:

```
Starting Go Routines

Waiting To Finish
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 a 13 14 15 16 17 b 18 19 c 20 21 d 22 23 e 24 25 f 26 g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
Terminating Program
```

The playground is deterministic in nature. Goroutines don't yield as often and don't run in multiple threads.