# RWMutex in Go is not working as expected

Tags: caching, go

I have written following sample program using sync.RWMutex.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// SessionData : capture session id and cc-request-number
type SessionData struct {
    id    string
    reqNo string
}

// SessionCache : cache for the SessionData
type SessionCache struct {
    sess map[SessionData]bool
    sync.RWMutex
}

// InitSessionCache : Init for SessionCache
func InitSessionCache() SessionCache {
    return SessionCache{sess: make(map[SessionData]bool)}
}

// Read : read value from session cache
func (s *SessionCache) Read(sd SessionData) bool {
    s.RLock()
    defer s.RUnlock()

    _, found := s.sess[sd]
    return found
}

func (s *SessionCache) Write(sd SessionData) {
    s.Lock()
    defer s.Unlock()
    fmt.Println("Entry not found for ", sd.id, sd.reqNo, "Creating the entry now")
    s.sess[sd] = true
}

func (s *SessionCache) chkDuplicate(sessionID string, Reqno string) bool {

    sd := SessionData{
        id:    sessionID,
        reqNo: Reqno,
    }

    found := s.Read(sd)
    if !found {
        s.Write(sd)
        return found
    }
    return found
}

func main() {
    mySessionData := InitSessionCache()

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go mySessionData.chkDuplicate("session1", "1")
        go mySessionData.chkDuplicate("session1", "1")
        go mySessionData.chkDuplicate("session1", "2")
        go mySessionData.chkDuplicate("session1", "2")
        go mySessionData.chkDuplicate("session1", "4")
        go mySessionData.chkDuplicate("session1", "2")
    }
    time.Sleep(300)
    fmt.Println(mySessionData)

}
```

when I run this program in playground https://play.golang.org/p/g93UtVxZ2dl
I see that it is working correctly as the write happens only 3 times for the unique values.

```
Entry not found for  session1 1 Creating the entry now
Entry not found for  session1 2 Creating the entry now
Entry not found for  session1 4 Creating the entry now
{map[{session1 1}:true {session1 2}:true {session1 4}:true] {{0 0} 0 0 0 0}}
```

however when I run the same program from my windows 10 machine (on VS Code) I see following output.

```
Entry not found for  session1 1 Creating the entry now
Entry not found for  session1 2 Creating the entry now
Entry not found for  session1 2 Creating the entry now
Entry not found for  session1 2 Creating the entry now
Entry not found for  session1 4 Creating the entry now
{map[{session1 1}:true {session1 2}:true {session1 4}:true] {{0 0} 0 0 0 0}}
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Why does this behaves differently on my Machine and Playground?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31297515/13860).

Comment: Your code works as expected though. `found := s.Read(sd)
    if !found {
        s.Write(sd)` --- these 3 operations run concurrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syncronisation between the call to `Read` and `Write`. All your goroutines are running concurrently, imagine if they all run up to this line and then yield to another goroutine:

`found := s.Read(sd)`

They will all return `false` because none of the goroutines have moved past this point. Now they all move on to the next line and believe that `found == false`, so all perform the `s.Write(sd)`.

You need to perform the Read and Write without unlocking. Maybe something like:

```
func (s *SessionCache) TryWrite(sd SessionData) err {
    s.Lock()
    defer s.Unlock()

    if _, found := s.sess[sd]; found {
        return fmt.Errorf("Entry already exists")
    }

    s.sess[sd] = true
}
```